# How to total all product by difference record in one table?

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have the following table, I want to get the total all of products:

```
prodcod | prodname | pricein | Qty | priceout

01      | Coca     | 12$     | 40  | 20$
02      | pepsi    | 6$      | 20  | 10$
03      | fanta    | 9$      | 50  | 15$
04      | M150     | 12$     | 10  | 20$
```

I want to get the total of Qty =120

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(Qty) AS TOTAL

FROM [TABLE_NAME]
```

Answer (score 1):

The SQL code is simple enough:

```
SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM Products
```

To call that from vb.net:

```
Dim Quantity As Integer
Using cn As New SqlConnection("connection string here"), _
      cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM Products", cn)

    cn.Open()
    Quantity = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)
End Using
```